# Computing the Chain Homotopy Group of two chain complexes of free abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I hear a basic course on algebraic topology and I have some difficulties with the following problem: Let $L$ and $K$ be chain complexes of free abelian groups, $H_{0}(K)= \mathbb{Z} / 2$ and $H_{i}(K)=0$ for $i \not = 0$. Also let $H_{0}(L)=0$ and $H_{1}(L)= \mathbb{Z} /4$. I now have to compute the group of homotopy classes of the chain maps from $K$ to $L$ $[K,L]$ I know that two chain-homotopic maps induce the same map on the homology groups but this thought didn't really get me anywhere. Could you help me to get an idea of what I have to do? Thank you kindly.

Comment: probably have to compute homology groups of the chain complex $\text{hom}(H_*(K),H_*(L)).$

Comment: @ziggurism Thank you, but I have to admit that I don't quite see yet how this would help me. Could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: Well the homotopy classes of maps depend only on the homotopy types, and the homotopy types of fibrant-cofibrant chain complexes are the quasi-isomorphism classes.

Comment: @ziggurism Unfortunately  those concepts are well beyond what I know about chain complexes. We only had a few very basic results about chain complexes and the chain homotopy classes (like for example that chain-homotopic maps induce the same map on the homology groups or that  free abelian chain complexes where the homologies are isomorphic the complexes are already homotopy equivalent). Maybey I should have stated that more clearly in the question

Comment: It should be possible to prove the result without recourse to the language of model categories.

Comment: Do you know what is the derived category ? The result @ziggurism has in mind can be stated in the following form : for a (bounded above) complex of free abelian groups $Hom_{\mathcal{K}}(K,L)=Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(K,L)$. The latter can be easily computed since you know the quasi-isomorphism classes of $K$ and $L$. (Here $\mathcal{K}$ denotes the homotopy category and $\mathcal{D}$ the derived category).

Comment: @Roland Ah, thank you. That's something I can work with. The derived category was not introduced in the course but I googled it and it seems quite understandable! (And it wouldn't be the first time that concepts not yet introduced are necessary for some problems in this course) Thank you a lot!

Comment: In fact, you can probably avoid the use of derived categories (depending on what result you have at hands), if you prove that your complexes are homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}\overset{\times 2}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and to $\mathbb{Z}\overset{\times 4}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ (properly shifted), and then compute the group of homotopy classes of maps between these two explicit complexes.

Comment: @Roland so the answer is $[K,L]=0$.

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev No it isn't. It is $Hom_D(\mathbb{Z/2Z,Z/4Z}[1])=\mathbb{Z/2Z}$.